# TypeError: 'str' object does not support object assignment

Tags: python

Working on a python program that takes input instructions from a text file and writes them to a dictionary within a list.
My error comes when I try to run an or_inst function:

```
def or_inst(contextStack, varName, arg1, arg2):
  checkExists(contextStack, arg1)
  checkExists(contextStack, arg2)
  for context in contextStack:
    if (lookup(contextStack, arg1) == 't' or lookup(contextStack, arg2) == 't'):
        assignValue(context, varName, 't')
    else:
        assignValue(context, varName, 'f')
```

where contextStack is the list with dictionary context
the input instructions are:

or d a b

and contextStack is:

('c':'f', 'b':'f', 'a':'t')

assignValue is:

```
def assignValue(contextStack, varName, value):
  print(contextStack, varName, value)
  for context in contextStack:
    context[varName] = value
```

I think the error is from using the string 't' in the value position (at least from what I've already looked up). What other options do I have?

Comment: contextStack is the list containing the dictionary 'context'. contextStack looks like [{'c':'f', 'b':'f', 'a':'t'}] at the time of the error

Comment: What are you trying to do with `assignValue` ?

Comment: lookup checks the dict in contextStack to find the dict key and returnt he value. for example: in 'or d a b', lookup(contextStack, arg1) finds 'a' in the dict and returns the value 't'

Comment: and assignValue is supposed to add to the dictionary the value (in this case 't') with the key (on this case 'd'). it works for the first 3 instruction which just set the values to varName (ex. in the case of set a t, it assigns the 'a' to have the value 't')

Comment: I don't know why you have written a method to replicate a built-in function of dictionaries. What is the point of `assignValue` when you can just do `context[varName] = value`?

Answer (score 0):

If `contextStack` in `assignValue` is really a dictionary, then when you loop over it using -

```
for context in contextStack:
```

The `context` would be the key in the dictionary (which I guess is a string, from your error) , you cannot do `context[varName] = value` .

If you aim is to change (or add) the value for `varnName` key in the `contextStack` dictionary to `value` , then you should simply use -

```
def assignValue(contextStack, varName, value):
    print(contextStack, varName, value)
    contextStack[varName] = value
```

Comment: when i run assignValue like that, i get the error that list indices must be int not str

Comment: Are you sure you didn;t also change the line - `assignValue(context, varName, 't')` to `assignValue(contextStack, varName, 't')` ? If you did, don't do that.